# Applying cutoff to data set with IDs

Tags: sas, logistic-regression

I am using SAS and managed to run `proc logistic`, which gives me a table like so.

```
Classification Table
Prob    Correct Incorrect   Percentages
Level   Event   Non-    Event   Non-    Correct Sensi-  Speci-  FALSE   FALSE
                Event           Event           tivity  ficity  POS     NEG  J
0       33      0       328     0       9.1     100     0       90.9    .    99
0.02    33      62      266     0       26.3    100     18.9    89      0   117.9
0.04    31      162     166     2       53.5    93.9    49.4    84.3    1.2 142.3
0.06    26      209     119     7       65.1    78.8    63.7    82.1    3.2 141.5
```

How do I include IDs for the rows of data in `lib.POST_201505_PRED` below that have at least 0.6 probability?

```
proc logistic data=lib.POST_201503 outmodel=lib.POST_201503_MODEL descending;
model BUYER = 
    age
    tenure
    usage
    payment
    loyalty_card
    /outroc=lib.POST_201503_ROC;
    Score data=lib.POST_201505 out=lib.POST_201505_PRED outroc=lib.POST_201505_ROC;
run;
```

I've been reading the [documentation](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63347/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_logistic_sect004.htm) and searching online but haven't found anything on it. I must be searching for the wrong keywords, as I presume this is a frequently used process.

Comment: So you built a model using `Proc Logistic` on a training set and you want to score a validation set? What has or should have a probability of 0.6?

Comment: Yes, and I also want to select the IDs with probability of 0.6 and above. I think my real question is how to associated the IDs with the probability scores

Comment: Please add more code

Comment: I added my `proc logistics` code. Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You just need an id-statement to tell SAS your ID-variable identifies your observations**;

```
proc logistic data=lib.POST_201503 outmodel=lib.POST_201503_MODEL descending;
    id ID; 
    model BUYER = age tenure usage payment loyalty_card
        /outroc=lib.POST_201503_ROC;
    Score data=lib.POST_201505 
        out=lib.POST_201505_PRED 
        outroc=lib.POST_201505_ROC;
run;
```

**Now your output contains all you need.** 
For instance to print the IDs that get had probability of at least 0.6 assigned of being a BUYER to them;

```
proc print data=lib.POST_201505_PRED (where=(P_1 GE 0.6));
    var ID P_1;
run;
```

**You find these `id yourKey;` statements throughout the statistical procedures in SAS**, for instance ;

```
proc univariate data=psydata.stroop;
    id Subject;
    var ReadTime;
run;
```

** will report the most extreme values of ReadTime as

[image]

;

Comment: I couldn't find anything on the `id ID;` snippet when I looked online for hours. Can you provide a reference for that?

Comment: I don't remember which document brought me on the right track, but it is very common in SAS/STAT to have an `ID yourKey` statement to identify your observations. See my edit above.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I just had to include the ids in `lib.POST_201505`